# how to pass data to a Tailwind modal using Laravel

Tags: modal-dialog, laravel-8, tailwind-css, pass-data

i have this code in tailwind

```
@foreach($studenti as $student) 
<a data-modal-toggle="defaultModal" data-target="#myModal{{$student->id }} href="#" class="hover:text-blue-700">{{$student->name}}</a>

and this is the Main modal 
<!-- Main modal -->
<div id="myModal{{$student->id}}" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" class="hidden overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden fixed top-0 right-0 left-0 z-50 w-full md:inset-0 h-modal md:h-full justify-center items-center">
    <div class="relative p-4 w-full max-w-2xl h-full md:h-auto">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700">
            <!-- Modal header -->
            <div class="flex justify-between items-start p-4 rounded-t border-b dark:border-gray-600">
                <h3 class="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                {{$alum->nombre}} {{$alum->apellpatern}} {{$alum->apellmatern}}
                </h3>
                <button type="button" class="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" data-modal-toggle="defaultModal">
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close modal</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="p-6 space-y-6">
                <p class="text-base leading-relaxed text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                    With less than a month to go before the European Union enacts new consumer privacy laws for its citizens, companies around the world are updating their terms of service agreements to comply.
                </p>
                <p class="text-base leading-relaxed text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                    The European Union’s General Data Protection Regulation (G.D.P.R.) goes into effect on May 25 and is meant to ensure a common set of data rights in the European Union. It requires organizations to notify users as soon as possible of high-risk data breaches that could personally affect them.
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="flex items-center p-6 space-x-2 rounded-b border-t border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-600">
                <button data-modal-toggle="defaultModal" type="button" class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">I accept</button>
                <button data-modal-toggle="defaultModal" type="button" class="text-gray-500 bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 rounded-lg border border-gray-200 text-sm font-medium px-5 py-2.5 hover:text-gray-900 focus:z-10 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300 dark:border-gray-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:focus:ring-gray-600">Decline</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endforeach
```

But when i pressed the  link it does not work, i am using data-target="#myModal{{$student->id }} in order to pass @student data to tailwind Main modal id="myModal{{$student->id}}",
it seems that this is not the proper way to pass data, i am using Laravel 8, anyhelp is appreciated
Thank you in advance

Omar

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: it does not do nothing, i am planning to do modal windows enterily using only html, css and Javascript

Comment: data-target does not work here in tailwind, only in bootstrap

Comment: Tailwind is CSS only framework - no javascript at all. All js logic should be implemented by you

Comment: Hi, I already solved my issue, i used data-modal-toggle="myModal{{$student->id}}" in <a>, and in modal too, i used the same data-modal-toggle="myModal{{$student->id}}", and that is all, i can pass data to tailwind modal window of each student, thank you very much for help

Answer (score 0):

That's not best way, but you can just wrap the modal button in a different foreach loop and the modal in another it should work